# missing required argument 'email'

Tags: javascript, node.js, command-line-interface

## Missing required argument 'email'

### Hello,

I'm trying to make a command line interface using nodejs since ive been trying to learn it better.
everything has been going to plan right up until now.
As you should know, since I quite clearly stated, I'm learning node so I'm not completely upfront with all the errors.
My interface is for managing customers and everything works fine, but this happens when I run

```
node commands.js add john doe 555-555-5555 john@gmail.com
```

through the command line. This is the error I get when running it.

```
error: missing required argument 'email'
```

Here is my code so if anyone would like to take a look.

```
const program = require('commander');
const {
    addCustomer,
    findCustomer
} = require('./index');

program
    .version('1.0.0')
    .description('Client Management System')

program
    .command('add <firstname> <lastname> <dob> <phone> <email>')
    .alias('a')
    .description('Add a customer')
    .action((firstname, lastname, dob, phone, email) => {
        addCustomer({firstname, lastname, dob, phone, email});
    }),

program
    .command('find <name>')
    .alias('f')
    .description('Find a customer')
    .action(name => findCustomer(name));

program.parse(process.argv);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you miss the DOB data ?

```
node commands.js add john doe 555-555-5555 john@gmail.com
```

should be something like

```
node commands.js add john doe 2011-1-2 555-555-5555 john@gmail.com
```

Comment: Me too. I always miss apostrophes and commas in my codes